# jQuery easing animations scroll effect on mouse wheel

Tags: jquery, scroll, easing

I've found a lot of jquery plugins that does similar effects but couldn't find anything that can do this: https://www.zoho.com/survey/

TIP: Try to scroll with mouse wheel.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at their source code ? https://www.zoho.com/survey/js/index-script.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

[One Page Scroll](http://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll)

[DEMO](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you want something more complete and able to work in old browsers as well (such as IE 8, Opera 12...), I would recommend [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

- [Living demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)
- [Web page](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/)
- [Github](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

Use of vertical an horizontal scrolls, anchor links, callbacks, navigation bars, linked menus...